# How to display a div dynamically based on a selected option in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a dropdown list in VueJS. I want to be able to display div's dynamically based on the option selected.

Here is the code

```js
export default {
 data(){
  return{
            selected: "Choose Option",
            options: [
                { id: 1, name: 'A' },
                { id: 2, name: 'B' },
                { id: 3, name: 'C' }
            ]
  }
  },
}
```

```html
<template>
 <div id="app" class="ui grid">

        <div>    
            <select class="ui dropdown" v-model="selected">
                <option>Choose Option</option>
                <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id">
                    {{option.name}}
                </option>
            </select>

            <div v-if="options[0].id === 1">
                HELLO
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

Every time I switch between options or when the app loads for the first time, the value "HELLO" remains as it is.

What wrong am I doing? How can I change this? Would appreciate if someone could help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `select` input is bonded to `selected` variable, `options` doesn't change. Did you mean `v-if="selected === 1"`?

Comment: Yes. It looks like I made that mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/279011/)

```
<div v-if="selected === 2">
  two
</div>
```

Where the div is checked against `selected`.

> Every time I switch between options or when the app loads for the first time, the value "HELLO" remains as it is.

Because the condition stays true `options[0].id === 1`.